# How to enumerate name of text files

Tags: java

How to create enumeration of text files with extension .txt, because this code is not working

```
enum Files {
   text1.txt, text2.txt, text3.txt ; 
}
```

Comment: Why exactly you are creating an enum for those names? Can you provide your use case? I think an enum is not the best fit for this problem.

Comment: Class SequenceInputStream(Enumeration<? extends InputStream> e) have argument of enumeration and use to bind two or more input streams in one stream. That's the reason

Comment: The `Enumeration` generic class is something completely different from an `enum`.  Please don't get them confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making a `Vector<InputStream>`, calling `add()` for each filename, then calling `elements()`, which returns an `Enumeration`.

Answer (score 0):

I done it on this way ant it works

```
FileInputStream fin1 = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");
FileInputStream fin2 = new FileInputStream("c:\\test1.txt");
FileInputStream fin3 = new FileInputStream("c:\\test2.txt");

Vector v = new Vector();

v.add(fin1);
v.add(fin2);
v.add(fin3);

Enumeration e = v.elements();

SequenceInputStream s = new SequenceInputStream(e);
```